# Client String Execution

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to allow players to execute scripts from a local script on my game.
(Not for malicious purposes, I'm trying to make a challenge to expose game weaknesses.)
**loadstring** doesn't work from the client, is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this module right here](https://www.roblox.com/library/4689019964/vLua-5-1-improved-VM). Insert the module into your local script, and require it:

```lua
-- at beginning of code
local loadstring = require(script:WaitForChild("Loadstring"))

-- an example
code = [[print("Hello world!")]]
local executable, compileFailReason = loadstring(code)
executable()

-- or simply...
loadstring(code)()
```